# How To Sum The Even Numbers Using Loop

Tags: java

I need help on this code I seem to have a problem regarding on summing the even numbers, what I want to happen is that the even numbers will be outputted and at the same time there will be an output where all the even numbers are summed within the inputted range of the user. I am just a beginner at coding and I hope some people can help me.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Loop
{
    //Start
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Enter Start Number") ;
        int start =console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter End Number") ;
        int end =console.nextInt();
        
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("The even numbers between "+start+" and "+end+" are the following: ");
        for (int r = start; r <= end; r++)
        {
        //if number%2 == 0 it means its an even number
        if(r % 2 == 0)
        {
        System.out.println(r);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally the advice is to way 24 hours to accept the answer. This allows the possibility of other answers.

Comment: @NomadMaker what would be the point to that? Other answers don't invalidate the first correct one.

Comment: @daniu The way I was told it was that mark as question as answered discouraged other answers, and there might be a better answer shortly.

Comment: I am new to Stack Overflow so I have no idea what NomadMaker and daniu is talking about sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use with `sum+=r;` and get the sum :

```
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Enter Start Number") ;
        int start =console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter End Number") ;
        int end =console.nextInt();
        
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("The even numbers between "+start+" and "+end+" are the following: ");
        for (int r = start; r <= end; r++)
        {
        //if number%2 == 0 it means its an even number
        if(r % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum += r;
        System.out.println(r);
        }
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of even numbers between :"+start +" - "+end +" is : "+sum);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Enter Start Number
10
Enter End Number
20
The even numbers between 10 and 20 are the following: 
10
12
14
16
18
20
The sum of even numbers between :10 - 20 is : 90
```

Comment: Thank you for answering kind sir, now I know what I was doing wrong. before my equation of sum is sum = r +2. and this really helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

A concise way using Java streams. Just putting it here so that you know that there is another way to do this:

```
int sum = IntStream.range(start, 1 + end).filter(num -> 0 == num % 2).peek(System.out::println).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Marcel - You may find the lambda expression and Java Stream API difficult in the beginning, it's worth learning for the long term. I highly recommend it to you.

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there

```
   int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("The even numbers between "+start+" and "+end+" are the following: ");
    for (int r = start; r <= end; r++)
    {
    if(r % 2 == 0)
    {
    sum = sum + r;
    System.out.println(r);
    }
    }
    System.out.println("the sum : "+sum);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, the sum = sum + r is the same as sum += r right?

Answer (score 1):

When you print an even number, also add it to `sum` and print the value of `sum` after the loop.

```
for (int r = start; r <= end; r++) {
    //if number%2 == 0 it means its an even number
    if(r % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(r);
        sum += r;
    }
}

System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why are you incrementing `r` by one, instead do this:

```
if (r % 2 == 1)  // if `r` is odd
    r++;

for (; r <= end; r+=2) {
    System.out.println(r);
    sum += r;
}

System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Comment: Noted, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify by a lot!
By creating a temporary variable `t`

1. If `start` is odd, initialise `t = start + 1`, otherwise `t = start`
2. Use a formula to calculate `sum` between two numbers
3. Also, increment the loop variable by `2` instead of `1`

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Start Number");
    int start = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter End Number");
    int end = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The even numbers between " + start + " and " + end + " are the following:");

    int t = start % 2 == 1 ? start + 1: start;
    int sum = ((t + end) / 2) * ((end - t + 2) / 2);

    while(t <= end) {
        System.out.println(t);
        t += 2;
    }
    
    System.out.println("The sum of even numbers between : " + start + " - " + end + " is : " + sum);
}
```

Note: If we make the use of bit-wise operators we can make replace the following

1. `int t = start % 2 == 1 ? start + 1: start;` by `int t = start + (start & 1);`
2. `int sum = ((t + end) / 2) * ((end - t + 2) / 2);` by `int sum = ((t + end) >> 1) * ((end - t + 2) >> 1);`

**Final Solution**

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Start Number");
    int start = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter End Number");
    int end = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The even numbers between " + start + " and " + end + " are the following:");

    int t = start + (start & 1);
    int sum = ((t + end) >> 1) * ((end - t + 2) >> 1);
    while(t <= end) {
        System.out.println(t);
        t += 2;
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of even numbers between : " + start + " - " + end + " is : " + sum);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will take note of this tips.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
   if(i%2==0){
      sum += i;
   }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * C program to print sum of all even numbers between 1 to n
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, n, sum=0;

    /* Input upper limit from user */
    printf("Enter upper limit: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=2; i<=n; i+=2)
    {
        /* Add current even number to sum */
        sum += i;
    }

    printf("Sum of all even number between 1 to %d = %d", n, sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:-
Enter upper limit: 10
Sum of all even number between 1 to 10 = 30